# Padleft function with a sequence number in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to add a progressive number of fixed length at the beginning of each row in a txt file. For example:

```
0001 aaaaaaaaaaa
0002 bbbbbbbbbb
...
0010 gggggggggg
```

I created a .bat file to run a PowerShell which should solve the problem:

```cmd
@echo off &setlocal
set "path=C:\Users..."
set "filein=%~1"
set "fileout=%filein%_out"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "& {(Get-Content %path%\%filein%.txt) |ForEach-Object {$_.Insert(0,($id++).PadLeft(10,'0'))} |Set-Content %path%\%fileout%.txt}"
```

But it doesn't work. Probably there's some syntax error.

Comment: What exactly `doesn't work` ? Do you get error messages?

Comment: Why not just do the whole thing in powershell. That is much simpler.

Comment: if there is a simple way can you explain? please

Comment: this is the error message Method invocation failed because [System.Int32] does not contain a method named 'PadLeft'.
At line:1 char:80
+ ... OC.txt) |foreach-object {$_.Insert(0,($id++).PadLeft(10,'0'))} |set-c ...
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: Please edit your question with further information rather than putting the error in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you added the [batch-file] tag - here is a pure Batch solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
(for /f "delims=" %%A in (input.txt) do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "index=00000!count!"
    echo !index:~-4! %%A
))>Output.txt
```

Comment: Simpler: initialize `set count=10000` and then, after `set /a count+=1`, just use `echo !count:~-4! %%A`

Comment: @Aacini: that's right, but I like this one better, because we*re not bound to zeros, but can also pad with spaces (or whatever).

Answer (score 3):

`($id++).PadLeft(10,'0')` fails, because `($id++)` is of type `[int]`, not `[string]`, and `[int]` has no `.PadLeft()` method.

Simply converting `($id++)` to a string is enough:

```
($id++).ToString().PadLeft(10,'0')
```

Also note that your sample output has a space between the padded number and the content of the line, so you'd have to use:

```
$_.Insert(0, ($id++).ToString().PadLeft(10,'0') + ' ')
```

---

As an aside:

- You don't need `call` in a batch file to call *executables* (`call` is only needed for calling *other batch files*, if you want the call to return).
- The PowerShell executable is in the `%PATH%` by default, so you can invoke it by name only, i.e., `powershell.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might workout for you -

```
$id = 1
$files = Get-Content "\\PathToYourFile\YourFile.txt"
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $Padded = $id.ToString("0000000000");
    $file.Insert(0, ($Padded));
    $id++
}
```

Use the `ToString()` method, instead of `PadLeft` to add progressive number of fixed length zeroes. That is much simpler and hassle-free.
Also, doing the entire operation in PowerShell will be much simpler.

You can also do this in a single line like -

```
$i = 1
Get-Content "\\PathToYourFile\YourFile.txt" | % { $_.Insert(0, ($i.ToString("0000000000"))); $i++ } | Set-Content ".\NewFileout.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure batch file solution, which does not ignore empty lines and is safe against all characters, even exclamantion marks (`!`):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set /A "IDX=0"
> "output.txt" (
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "input.txt"') do (
        set /A "IDX+=0"
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "IDX=0000!IDX!"
        echo !IDX:~-4! !LINE:*:=!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```